# Submitting a multi dimensional array with jQuery and YUI

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, yui

Hey Guys, this is really bugging me now so if you could help me out that would be amazing.

I'm using jQuery and YUI and I'm trying to send a multidimensional array via json to php but for some reason I can't grab text to put in the array from an a span! Go figure! No matter how I try I can't seem to add it. If I manually add test data into WeekDays[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uttws.jpg) =  and that works but for some reason it wont grab the text from the span!

The alert on click works and outputs the information out of the span but i can't seem to set an Array value

```
function checkDay(checkbox) {
    var checked = '0';
    if ($('#' + checkbox).is(':checked')) {
        checked = '1';
    } else {
        checked = '0';

    }
    return checked;
}


var WeekDays = new Array(7);
WeekDays[0] = new Array();
WeekDays[0][0] = checkDay('chxMonday');
WeekDays[0][2] = $('#results22Monday').text();
WeekDays[1] = new Array();
WeekDays[1][0] = checkDay('chxTuesday');
WeekDays[1][3] = new Array();
WeekDays[1][4] = $('#results22Tue').text();
WeekDays[2] = new Array();
WeekDays[2][0] = checkDay('chxWednesday');
WeekDays[2][5] = $('#results22Wednesday').text();
WeekDays[3] = new Array();
WeekDays[3][0] = checkDay('chxThursday');
WeekDays[3][6] = $('#results22Thursday').text();
WeekDays[4] = new Array();
WeekDays[4][0] = checkDay('chxFriday');
WeekDays[4][7] = $('#results22Friday').text();
WeekDays[5] = new Array();
WeekDays[5][0] = checkDay('chxSaturday');
WeekDays[5][8] = $('#results22Saturday').text();
WeekDays[6] = new Array();
WeekDays[6][0] = checkDay('chxSunday');
WeekDays[6][9] = $('#results22Sunday').text();



WeekDays = YAHOO.lang.JSON.stringify(WeekDays);


$('#btnUpdateSettings').click(function () {
    alert($('#results22Tue').text());
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            contactID: d.act_contactID,
            apiCPolicy: $('[name=txtCpolicy]').val(),
            apiNewRegistrations: $('[name=rdoRegister]').val(),
            apiInterval: $('[name=cboBooking]').val(),
            apiMaxDate: $('[name=cboMaxDate]').val(),

            apiTimes: WeekDays,

            method: 'updateWebBooking',
            dataType: 'json'
        },
        success: function () {
            console.log("welldone, you've updated!");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ooooppps!");
        }
    });
});
```

When I check the console logo I get the screen below, showing the array is empty.

[image]

I've marked the space where I want the text to appear but its not there! Its so infuriating. The same goes for all the other array results

Any ideas you'd be really helping me out

UPDATE

the alert does work and outputs as show below, but its just not added to the array!
[image]

So I'm still non the wiser its not being added.

UPDATE

That's really weird, I do have the index set to the one below but when I pasted my code into the question the first time the index was change! Odd! Anyway, its not working when the array indexes are correct!

```
var WeekDays = new Array(7);
            WeekDays[0] =  new Array();
            WeekDays[0][0] = checkDay('chxMonday');
            WeekDays[0][1] = $('#results22Monday').text();
            WeekDays[1] =  new Array();
            WeekDays[1][0] = checkDay('chxTuesday');
            WeekDays[1][1] = new Array();
            WeekDays[1][1]  = $('#results22Tue').text();
            WeekDays[2] =  new Array();
            WeekDays[2][0] = checkDay('chxWednesday');
            WeekDays[2][1] =  $('#results22Wednesday').text();
            WeekDays[3] =  new Array();
            WeekDays[3][0] = checkDay('chxThursday');
            WeekDays[3][1] = $('#results22Thursday').text();
            WeekDays[4] =  new Array();
            WeekDays[4][0] = checkDay('chxFriday');
            WeekDays[4][1] = $('#results22Friday').text();
            WeekDays[5] =  new Array();
            WeekDays[5][0] = checkDay('chxSaturday');
            WeekDays[5][1] = $('#results22Saturday').text();
            WeekDays[6] =  new Array();
            WeekDays[6][0] = checkDay('chxSunday');
            WeekDays[6][1] = $('#results22Sunday').text();
```

UPDATE

Ok I feel I need to give you guys a more comprehensive question to fill you in on what I'm trying to do as there is probably a much more eloquent way so achieving this. the images below are probably the best way to show this. When I press the update table button It populates the blank area on the right with a table which includes check boxes which are at certain increments set earlier on in the form. Its these check boxes I want to save along with whether the check box for that day has been checked. If the day is unchecked I want the table to be cleared so no data is sent to the database for that day. Thats why I wanted to save then in a multidimensional array and then serialize them, but I can' get it to work

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: remove this WeekDays[1][1] = new Array();

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Please try to alert - $('#results22Monday').text();

Because, in my opinion, .text() is the culprit.

As you can see, the JSON is created in the correct format(7,2 array) and the checkDay function is populating the values correctly.</strike>

So please check

1. which HTMLElement is results22Monday and the others?
2. does it have a text? or do you need a val()?

Oh, We wanted a 7 x 2 array right?

If so, the indexing of the child array is all wrong.
Try altering this one line and tell me if the first value is shown at firebug console?

<strike>`WeekDays[0][2] = $('#results22Monday').text();`</strike>
to
`WeekDays[0][1] = $('#results22Monday').text();`

See we wanted results22Monday to some as the second element of child array(ie. at index 1)

I would also rewrite the top part of your code like this, since its a lot cleaner.

```
function checkDay(checkbox) {
    return ($('#' + checkbox).is(':checked')) ? '1' : '0';
}


var WeekDays = new Array(7);
WeekDays[0] = [checkDay('chxMonday'), $('#results22Monday').text()];
WeekDays[1] = [checkDay('chxTuesday'), $('#results22Tue').text()];
WeekDays[2] =  [checkDay('chxWednesday'), $('#results22Wednesday').text()];
WeekDays[3] =  [checkDay('chxThursday'), $('#results22Thursday').text()];
WeekDays[4] =  [checkDay('chxFriday'), $('#results22Friday').text()];
WeekDays[5] =  [checkDay('chxSaturday'), $('#results22Saturday').text()];
WeekDays[6] =  [checkDay('chxSunday'), $('#results22Sunday').text()];

//as its not a good practice to re-initialise the same variable
var jsonedWeekDays = YAHOO.lang.JSON.stringify(WeekDays);
```

Comment: Check the update above but when I alert the text it does come back with the values.

Comment: Tried the code above and its still not working, I'm going to post above a more comprehensive explanation of what I'm trying to do to see if it can be approached from a different angle

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but you might wanna use [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) instead of `YAHOO.lang.JSON.stringify()`.

and your function `checkDay()` is better written this way,

```
function checkDay(checkbox) {
    return $('#' + checkbox).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
}
```

and to your problem, I think you just forgot to wrap it in a [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) handler

demo

[with `.ready()`](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/WAPrn/) - works ok, alerts the text.

[without `.ready()`](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/WAPrn/1/) - did not alert the text.

if problem still persist, maybe we need some more info/codes from you which you think will help us solve the problem.